# App built with buildozer crashes after the loading screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I've been building a Kivy app, and now it's time to make an apk file to try running the app on my Android phone. I've rebuilt the app more than ten times, and every time the app crashed right after the loading screen. I've seen a few Github threads about some similar crash logs, and most people were using a Realme or Oppo phone. Because my current phone is from Realme, I ran the app on the newest Pixel emulator in Android Studio with the same result.

Crash log from the emulator: https://gist.github.com/JanBartos6/bdfa85e05f66689a602f99c5065e5771

The buildozer.spec file:
https://gist.github.com/JanBartos6/04a3786a9d754fda8e4f4e505a81a528